# Many inputs for activity node vs merge node

Tags: uml, modeling

What is the difference between joining  n activities with one activity and joining n activities with merge node and then the merge node with one activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand the UML specification:

> A merge node is a control node that brings together multiple alternate
>   flows. It is not used to synchronize concurrent flows but to accept
>   one among several alternate flows. All tokens offered on incoming
>   edges are offered to the outgoing edge. There is no synchronization of
>   flows or joining of tokens.

On the other hand,

> ... an action can only begin execution when it has been offered control tokens on all incoming control flows and all its input pins have been offered object tokens sufficient for their multiplicity. The action begins execution by accepting all the offers of control and object tokens allowed by input pin multiplicity.

Comment: Could you explain what the "token", "controll token" ist?

Comment: Informally, it is something like an "execution pointer". Activity diagrams model a "flow" of tokens. A control token is placed at the initial node when the activity starts, then it "flows" through the edges (arrows) from each activity node to the following.

Comment: ... and the difference between joining flows in activity node and joining them with join node?

Comment: A merge is like a pipe union (i.e. there is no waiting for the other flows). I'm not sure about the semantics of Action, since it seems to include an implicit join, but I have always drawn join nodes explictly (a join synchronizes incoming flows, and execution resumes once every incoming edge has been reached).

Answer (score 1):

**Merge Node**
[image]

This brings multiple alternate flows together . 

If two or more inflows are received by merge symbol, the outflow executed.

**Join Node**
[image]

This synchronizes two or more inflows and produce a single flow.

Outflow from a join cannot be executed until all inflows have been received.

Comment: The [uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#join-node) adds to this: "Join nodes have a join specification which is Boolean value specification using the names of the incoming edges to specify the conditions under which the join will emit a token." -- "The **default join specification** is the reserved string 'and'. It is equivalent to a specification that requires at least one token offered on each incoming edge"

Comment: Also: "The join specification is evaluated whenever a new token is offered on any incoming edge.". I.e. using join specification called 'or', I would assume that the join node emits a control token if any of the incoming edges offers a control token.

Comment: See also the [UML 2.5.1 specifications](https://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/17-12-05.pdf) section 15.3.3.4